# How can I change the appearance of digiKam?

Tags: ubuntu, photivo, digikam

I am very fond of [**digiKam**](http://www.digikam.org/). I am. Together with [**photivo**](http://photivo.org/photivo/start) I believe they're the two most competent programs to edit RAW photography. But the looks on digiKam don't convince me. At least not on Ubuntu 11.10. I've been trying to solve this problem, attempting to make it look a bit more sophisticated, but nothing seems to do it. I found [these instructions](http://www.digikam.org/drupal/node/26) on the digiKam site, but they don't suit me as I can't afford to put in the time and effort that crafting a new theme requires. Also, [this discussion](http://digikam.1695700.n4.nabble.com/Theme-apparence-in-different-distributions-td3051490.html) appeared to be promising, but it's proven to be feckless; the few users there each state they have the same problem, but nobody really gives the solution. Remember that I am running Ubuntu 11.10 with the Cinnamon desktop environment. Here's a screenshot of digiKam, and below that one there's a shot of the much better-looking photivo. If I can get digiKam anywhere near that, it's a win for me. In fact, even changing *something* about its appearance would do it! Thanks in advance.

[image: digiKam running on Ubuntu 11.10 (Cinnamon desktop)]

[image: photivo under the same OS]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is change the gtk theme. This will change what the widgets that digiKam uses look like.

On Gnome 2, I would say:

- use System -> Preferences -> Appearance
- if a good dark theme isn't there:

  - look at the package manager and check for gtk themes that you could install
- if none of those are what you want:

  - you'll have to go look at http://gnome-look.org/ and download and install a theme from there.

I think that some of this might apply to Gnome 3 but YMMV.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Dan. I had read this somewhere, though. It doesn't look like a real solution to me, since I'm not changing anything within the program itself, just the way the desktop environment renders it. If I logged onto say, Unity, the program would look the same, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 3):

This has worked for me:
*"To add themes, you will have to install an extra pack­age (as decribed here) like this:
sudo apt-get install kde-workspace-data"*
source: http://svenbuschbeck.net/wordpress/2012/05/add-themes-to-digikam-without-kde/

blessings!

Comment: `Package kde-workspace-data is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source` – Ubuntu-MATE 16.04. And my digikam looks really illegible with a (system-wide) darj theme (white font on nearly-white background...)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this works for older versions, but on Digikam version 5.6.0, if you first click on "Image Editor" in the top left corner and on the new window that comes up click on "Settings" then about half way down you will see "themes" there are 10 different themes to pick from my favorites being "GrayCard" and "LowKey" hope that helps someone.

- Image Editor
  -Settings
      -Themes

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (Ubuntu 18.04, 18.10). The solution was to sue the AppImage version of Digikam instead of the PPA or software store. The AppImage has the correct (neutral/grey) font background that matches the themes.

Comment: Do you need a lawyer to sue the AppImage version?  :-)